# Why can't Mathematica DSolve my equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve

$\begin{cases}
v(t) = A \cdot e^{kt} \\
v(t) = s'(t) \\
s(0) = 0 \\
v(0) = A \\
v(6000) = 299792458 \\
s(6000) = 2.37 \cdot 10^{16}
\end{cases}$

for $A$ and $k$.

But neither of

```
DSolve[{v[t] == s'[t], v[6000] == 299792458, s[6000] == 2.37*10^(16),  
        s[0] == 0, v[t] == a*E^(k*t)}, v[t], t]

DSolve[{v[t] == s'[t], v[6000] == 299792458, s[6000] == 2.37*10^(16), 
        s[0] == 0, v[t] == a*E^(k*t)}, s[t], t]
```

Why, and how do I solve it?

Comment: Several things: if you know `v[t]` then this is not a variable in the equation. Also, your equation for `s[t]` is first order and you're trying to impose two conditions.

Comment: If s'[t]=v[t]=A Exp[kt] so you have s[t]=A/k Exp[k t]+c, and with s[0]=0 follows that c=-a/k. With that you can solve it further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sol = First@DSolve[{s'[t] == a*Exp[k t], s[0] == 0}, s[t], t];
```

Displacement:

```
S[t] = s[t] /. sol
```

> $$ \frac{a \left(e^{k t}-1\right)}{k}$$

Speed:

```
  V[t] = D[s[t] /. sol, t]
```

> $$a e^{k t}$$

Solution.

```
 NSolve[{Rationalize[2.37*10^16, 0] == (a (-1 + Exp[k t]))/k, 
 299792458 == a Exp[k t]} /. t -> 6000, {k, a}, Reals]
```

> $$\{\{k\to -0.00199474,a\to 4.72755\times 10^{13}\}\}$$

Answer (score 3):

Building up from [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html)...

```
sol = DSolveValue[{s'[t] == A Exp[k t], s[0] == 0}, s, t];
s0 = Rationalize[2.37 10^16, 0];
v0 = 299792458;

NSolve[{sol[6000] == s0, sol'[6000] == v0}, {A, k}, Reals]
(* {{A -> 4.72755*10^13, k -> -0.00199474}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your use of `v[t]` doesn't add any new information that isn't already in `s[t]`.  It's not really a variable we solve for, so just use `s[t]`.

Next, you are overspecifying the problem like @b.gatessucks says.  The differential equation has one constant of integration, because it is first order.  We can only apply one boundary condition in this case.  Lets use `s[0]==0`.

```
DSolve[ {s'[t]==A*Exp[k*t], s[0]==0}, s[t], t]
```

This gives:

```
s[t] -> A*(Exp[k*t] - 1)/k
```

Now we can apply the other conditions algebraically to solve for `A` and `k`.  You could do that with `Solve` or `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 2):

*[Edit: Rewrote and expanded explanation of how to set up `DSolve` and why it fails.]*

You were almost there....

*First,* I want to show how such a problem should be specified, if you want `DSolve` to handle it all for you. `DSolve` can do it, provided such a system is solvable by *Mathematica* to begin with.  Understanding how `DSolve` works with such equations helps with using `DSolve` as a tool.  This is an important aspect of this question.  *Second,* this system is at the boundary of what is solvable, when treated as a whole.  It is also helpful to understand where such limitations lie.  *Finally,* in this case, it will appear more efficient, from the human user point of view, to take a high-school algebra approach and solve each thing in turn, using the result to solve the next thing.

*1.* What `DSolve` thinks of as "variables" fall into two classes, dependent variables and independent variables.  `DSolve` solves for dependent variables.  It does not solve for independent variables or other symbols that we might term "parameters."  Dependent variables have the form of functions of the independent variable(s), such as `s[t]` or `a[t]`.  `DSolve` also solves differential equations.  These two restrictions, that it solves differential equations for dependent variables, limit the sort of functional equations that can be solved.

There are two issues with the OP's set up, constant parameters to be solved for and the function equation `v[t] == a*E^(k*t)`.  For the constants `a`, `k`, we can change them to dependent variables `a[t]`, `k[t]` and specify their derivatives to be zero.  It may seem lame-brained that `DSolve` cannot handle a simple equation such as `v[t] == a[t] * E^(k[t] * t)`. It can handle similar equations under limited conditions, but `E^(k[t] * t)` does not meet the conditions (see [`tutorial/DSolveIntroductionToDAEs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroductionToDAEs.html) and [`tutorial/DSolveExamplesOfDAEs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveExamplesOfDAEs.html), which are limited to linear DAEs with constant coefficients, which seem to be the limitations).  If we try, we get an obscure error message (see note at end):

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

However, we can differentiate the equation to get the equivalent initial value problem,

```
D[v[t] == a[t] * E^(k[t] * t), t],  v[0] == a[0]
```

*2.* Now, instead of a message, it just runs a long time.  I will discuss this difficulty next.  For now, these are the alterations that (theoretically) transform the system into one `DSolve` will handle.

Now to the second point, which addresses some practical limitations of solving systems.  *Mathematica* is strongest at solving algebraic systems and next at transcendental systems that can be reduced to algebraic systems.  As the number of equations and variables increase, the requirements for time and memory generally increase as well.  In the OP's system, clearly the problematic term is `E^(k[t] * t)`.  It has the unknown in the exponent and so is transcendental. Even when `k[t]` is viewed as a constant, it is equivalent to `const^t`, which is still transcendental.  Furthermore, when `s'[t]` is integrated, `k[t]` will appear in the denominator, making `k[t]` appear in both an algebraic and a transcendental way.  This means we've wandered into a weaker area of equation-solving.

*3.* Finally, a solution.  It may be possible for *Mathematica* to solve the whole system, given enough time.  Breaking down a complicated system into bite-size pieces sometimes helps it out and is smarter approach here.  A minimal approach would be to eliminate a condition involving the difficult term with `k[t]`.  Indeed, if we omit the initial value for `v[0]` and solve for it afterwards, *Mathematica* reaches the solution rather quickly.

```
vars = {s, v, a, k};

{foo} = DSolve[
   {v[t] == s'[t], v[6000] == 299792458, s[6000] == 2.37*10^(16), 
    s[0] == 0, D[v[t] == a[t]*E^(k[t]*t), t], (*v[0] == a[0],*)
    a'[t] == 0, k'[t] == 0}, vars, t];
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
v[0] - a[0] /. foo // Simplify[#, C[2] ∈ Reals] & // Together // Numerator // # == 0 &;
csol = Solve[% && C[2] ∈ Reals]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

```
(*  {{C[2] -> -0.00199474}, {C[2] -> 0.}}  *)

dsol = foo /. First[csol];  (* ignore the trivial solution C[2] -> 0. *)
Thread[Through[vars[t]] -> (Through[vars[t]] /. dsol // N)] // Simplify
(*
  {s[t] -> 2.37002*10^16 - 2.37002*10^16 E^(-0.00199474 t) - 1.28246*10^-7 t, 
   v[t] -> -1.74637*10^-7 + 4.72755*10^13 E^(-0.00199474 t), 
   a[t] -> 4.72755*10^13,
   k[t] -> -0.00199474}
*)
```

It's kinda too bad that `DSolve` couldn't the whole system, including `C[2]` by itself, though.

The same approach can be taken to find the exact solution to the general equation.

```
Assuming[v2 ∈ Reals && s2 ∈ Reals,
 {foo} = DSolve[
   {v[t] == s'[t], v[t2] == v2, s[t2] == s2, s[0] == 0, 
    D[v[t] == a[t]*E^(k[t]*t), t], (*v[0] == a[0],*)a'[t] == 0, 
    k'[t] == 0}, vars, t];
 ceqn = v[0] - a[0] /. foo // Simplify[#, C[2] ∈ Reals] & // 
     Together // Numerator // # == 0 &;
 csol = Solve[ceqn, C[2]]
 ]
(*  {{C[2] -> (t2 v2 + s2 ProductLog[-((E^(-((t2 v2)/s2)) t2 v2)/s2)])/(s2 t2)}} *)
```

Then `dsol` etc. as above.  (The `ProductLog` shows up because `k` appears both in the exponential function and outside in a way that just falls within reach of *Mathematica's* capabilities.)

*Note on the `Solve::svars` message:*
This is an obscure message and it seems it might be possible to improve it.  Internally, `DSolve` tries to solve for the derivatives of the variables involved in the differential equations, including in this case `v'[t]`.  Since `v'[t]` is missing, `Solve` gives an error.  I think what normally happens is that `DSolve` either complains about equations not being differential equations (`DSolve::deqx`) due to missing derivatives or treats the system as a differential-algebraic equation.  It is possible here that it checks for derivatives, tries the system as a DAE (since `v'[t]` is missing), rejects it as a DAE, and goes back to solving an ODE but without noticing that `v'[t]` is missing.